# slsvcutil.exe Proxy and Interfaces

Tags: wcf, interface, proxy, xamarin.ios, svcutil.exe

Is it possible when using slsvcutil.exe to generate a proxy through the command line not to have the proxy file output the Interface in an Asynchronous fashion.

For example, if I have a function "foo()" on the serverside in the Interface, when I generate the proxy using Slsvcutil.exe, it makes two functions in the interface definition in the proxy named "BeginFoo()" and "EndFoo()".

All I want is "Foo()", I don't need the other two methods.

Is this possible? I'm using the proxy with Monotouch which is why I need to use Slsvcutil.exe but don't need the Asynchronous methods.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the Asynch methods are needed on the iPhone making this a moot question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to copy the ServiceReference from a Visual Studio Project and use the Interface and write the Servie and ServiceChannel maualy. Like: [Monotouch/WCF: How to consume the wcf service without svcutil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054581/monotouch-wcf-how-to-consume-the-wcf-service-without-svcutil)

But it's without svcutil and need some more work