# How to override ClientBase.CreateChannel in mono on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, wcf, mono, xamarin.ios

I'm moving a .NET WCF application to Mono for use in iOS.  Because Mono in iOS does not support dynamic code generation, I need to override `ClientBase.CreateChannel`, as indicated in this post:

[Monotouch/WCF: How to consume the wcf service without svcutil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054581/monotouch-wcf-how-to-consume-the-wcf-service-without-svcutil)

This solution uses the generic `ChannelBase<TChannel>`. While this class is defined as an inner class of `ClientBase<TChannel>` in .Net 4.0, I couldn't find it in the Mono source. There appears to be an unimplemented version of the non-generic `ChannelBase` in `System.ServiceModel.Channels`, but I don't think this is used here.

If anyone has gotten this solution to work, could you please elaborate on how you accessed `ClientBase<TChannel>`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We eventually found `ChannelBase<TChannel>` as an inner class of `ClientBase<TChannel>`.  It was marked as internal.  We had to remove the internal modifier in order to use the class and recompile mono, but then the solution in the previously referenced post worked.

I can't explain why `ChannelBase<TChannel>` is marked as internal.  This does not seem to match its definition in .Net.

Comment: Looking at Mono's source code, it is marked as `protected internal` in Monotouch (which is based on the Silverlight profile) and `internal` in all other versions.  Looking at the MSDN docs shows me that class only exists in Silverlight and .NET 4.0 and later.  I suppose the reason for the `internal` modifier was that it didn't exist in .NET 2.0.  I'll fix this for you.

Comment: Fixed in mono/master commit `c0e3517`.  However, this should not affect Monotouch for you, the class was already marked as `protected` there.

Comment: Thanks Martin.  Doesn't protected internal still mean that the class can only be used from within the assembly where it is defined?  Generally, ChannelBase<TChannel> would be used in other assemblies that override the CreateChannel method, as in my case.

Comment: No, it means either protected or internal - and it becomes protected outside the assembly that it's defined in.  So when you override it, you use "protected override".