# WCF in Xamarin iOS: adding an HTTP header to service operation calls

Tags: wcf, xamarin.ios

I'd like to add an HTTP header with user token each time the iOs client calls the WCF service. I found two way for doing it more or less transparently: via `WebOperationContext` and via an implementation of `IClientMessageInspector`. None of those has worked for me yet, though.

I could not bind the message inspector to an Endpoint via `IEndpointBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)` because the property ClientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors throws the NotImplementedException.

WebOperationContext did not help me either. The following code of Windows console app works well, the header is read by the service.

```
var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IDataService>(binding, endPointAddress);
IDataService client = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
using (new OperationContextScope((IClientChannel)client))
{
    WebOperationContext woc = new WebOperationContext(OperationContext.Current);
    woc.OutgoingRequest.Headers["X-Test42"] = "header value";
    var data = client.GetData();
}
```

The code for the iOs differs a bit because I can't use ChannelFactory for dynamic proxy generation. I created implementations of `ClientBase<IDataService>` and `ClientBase<IDataService>.ChannelBase<IDataService>` according to
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10056431/456181

The property DataServiceClient.ContextChannel returns the instance of `ClientBase<IDataService>.ChannelBase<IDataService>`.

```
DataServiceClient client = new DataServiceClient(binding, endPointAddress);
using (new OperationContextScope(client.ContextChannel))
{
    WebOperationContext woc = new WebOperationContext(OperationContext.Current);
    woc.OutgoingRequest.Headers["X-Test42"] = "header value";
    var data = client.GetData();
}
```

The header "X-Test42" does not get to the WCF service.

Can anybody suggest how to adjust any of those two methods or any other method of adding an HTTP header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use a message header instead of an HTTP header. It fits well the purpose and I don't need `WebOperationContext` that is not available in portable class libraries.
The operation code is pretty straightforward.

```
using (new OperationContextScope((DataServiceClientChannel)Channel))
{
    MessageHeader mhead = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("member.token", "", userToken);
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(mhead);
    result = Channel.GetData();
}
```