# WCF Client throws Null Reference Exception for iOS Unity builds

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, wcf

**Context**

I used [this tutorial](http://gyanendushekhar.com/2016/04/21/how-to-call-wcf-service-in-unity/) to build a very basic WCF server and client and I am trying to get it running on an iOS device. I am able to build the application in Unity and in XCode and I am able to connect to the server in the Editor. But I am getting a Null Reference Exception when I actually try to connect the client to the server.

The stack trace shows that this error is being thrown by the `System.ServiceModel` class.

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[TChannel].CreateChannel () [0x00000] in <c9bd1c5fa2104489802ea2feced48e51>:0
at callService.Start () [0x0001a] in C:\Users\QA\Documents\Codebase\WCFTest\Assets\Scripts\callService.cs:16
```

Here is the proxy class that I generated with the `svcutil.exe` tool found in the Unity installation directory.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
 
 
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="IService1")]
public interface IService1 {
 
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataResponse")]
    string GetData(string name, int value);
}
 
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public interface IService1Channel : IService1, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel {
}
 
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class Service1Client : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<IService1>, IService1 {
 
    public Service1Client() {
    }
 
    public Service1Client(string endpointConfigurationName) :
            base(endpointConfigurationName) {
    }
 
    public Service1Client(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) :
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
    }
 
    public Service1Client(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) :
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
    }
 
    public Service1Client(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) :
            base(binding, remoteAddress) {
    }
 
    public string GetData(string name, int value) {
        return base.Channel.GetData(name, value);
    }
}
```

I have found a few threads online with related errors that have given me some hints as to why this `System.ServiceModel` library would be throwing a `NullReferenceException` at runtime. Including [this page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptingRestrictions.html) which indicates that some .NET libraries that might be referenced by `System.ServiceModel` are not compatible with iOS and thus might be stripped out somewhere in the build process. I have tried several things but have had no luck so far.

- I have tried adding a linker file to make sure parts of the `System.ServiceModel` class are not being stripped out.
- I have tried using different versions of the `System.ServiceModel`. I added these [duplex versions of the library](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/z05gp6zsqhshvpx/AABYCEScibsKbzP4V5QZbKU6a) that were shared by a user on .
  I have also tried using the version of the library found in the Unity Installation path at:
  `C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.17f1\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono\2.0-api`
- I have tried overriding the CreateChannels() method which is often cited as necessary to avoid having code that uses dynamic code generation like [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054581/monotouch-wcf-how-to-consume-the-wcf-service-without-svcutil)

Answer (score 1):

After many trial and error attempts at using different `svcutil` commands and `System.ServiceModel` DLLs from different places I found [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/internals/available-assemblies) which indicated which version of `System.ServiceModel` was compatible with `Xamarin.iOS` (which I presumed would have similar compatibility limitations to Unity).

Since Windows Phone uses Silverlight and is built with Xamarin I used the `System.ServiceModel` and `System.XML.Serialization` that can be found in the Windows Phone SDK folder:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\MDILXAPCompile\Framework`

In order to get this folder I had to download an old .iso version of the Windows Phone sdk [from this site](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/) and I had to generate a new proxy class using the `SLSVCutil` executable found in a nearby folder:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools`

Using the silverlight versions of the library requires some minor changes to the client class in Unity as follows:

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class CallService : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI display = null;
    void Start()
    {
        EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://192.168.1.15/WcfService/Service1.svc/WcfDemoService");
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        Service1Client client = new Service1Client(binding, endpoint);

        client.GetDataCompleted += PrintToScreen;
        client.GetDataAsync("brennan", 10);
    }

    private void PrintToScreen(object sender, GetDataCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string resultString = e.Result;
        Debug.LogWarning(resultString);
        display.text = resultString;
    }
}
```